# ¿Cómo puedo cortar una iteración usando do while y un ciclo for?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Estoy haciendo un programa con un arreglo de objetos de 20 posiciones.

Necesito hacer que cada vez que se agrega un objeto al arreglo se debe preguntar al usuario si desea agregar otro y no obligar al usuario a ingresar los 20 registros de una vez.

El problema que tengo es que al terminar de llenar los datos necesito preguntar si desea registrar mas sedes, entonces si el usuario le da que no, se corta la iteración y el programa debe de salirse del for para que no se siga repitiendo, y si el usuario le da que si quiere seguir registrando sedes el do while debe seguir repitiendo el proceso de llenado hasta que el usuario ya no quiera.

Pero no logro hacerlo, ya que el do while no me funciona y el for sigue pidiéndome llenar el arreglo hasta las 20 posiciones, pero luego de terminar el primer llenado, o sea terminar de llenar la pregunta de ingrese el estado, debo preguntar desea registrar mas sedes  y como mencione debe repetir todo el proceso o salirse.

```
bool bandera = false;
string respuesta;
int opcion;
Sede registro = new Sede();
Sede[] arreglo_sede = new Sede[20];
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_sede.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Proceso de Registro de Sedes.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Id de Sede :");
        registro.Id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la sede :");
        registro.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Direccion :");
        registro.Direccion = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Estado /n");
        Console.WriteLine("1.activo / 2.inactivo");
        opcion =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (opcion == 1)
            {
                registro.Estado = true;
            }
        if (opcion == 2)
            {
                registro.Estado= false;
            }
        else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opcion incorrecta");
            }
        arreglo_sede[i] = registro;
    }
    bandera= true;
    Console.WriteLine("Desea registrar mas sedes? SI/NO");
    respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
    if (respuesta.ToLower().Equals("si")) bandera = false;
    
} while (bandera);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! SEgun la [documentacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements) (que es lo primero que tenes que leer), existe una forma de cortar una iteracion (cualquiera) y eso es usando un break

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: gracias creo que me explique mejor jejejej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tengo una solución a tu problema:

Lo mas importante, veo que validas si el usuario quiere registrar mas sedes.

```
Console.WriteLine("Desea registrar mas sedes? SI/NO");
respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
if (respuesta.ToLower().Equals("si")) bandera = false;
```

Pero estas validando mal. Estas validando que cuando sea "si" sea falso. Entonces cuando el usuario ingrese algo diferente va a seguir siendo true. En este caso mejor validalo con:
`if (respuesta.ToLower().Equals("no")) bandera = false;` o
`if (respuesta.ToLower().Equals("si")) bandera = true;`

Que seria lo mismo a decir: Si es "no" entonces false (no entra en el do while).
O el otro caso: Si es "si" entonces es true (sigue entrando en el do while).

**Sugerencias:**

1. Cuando necesites llenar un objeto dentro de un ciclo (for, while, etc), lo mejor es que inicialices el objeto en null y dentro del bucle lo inicialices como un objeto del tipo que sea. Esto se hace para que cuando ingreses el objeto al arreglo, este objeto vaya con los valores del usuario y así no se duplique con los valores de objetos anteriores. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
        bool bandera = false;
        string respuesta;
        int opcion;
        Sede registro = null;

        Sede[] arreglo_sede = new Sede[20];
        do {

            for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_sede.Length; i++)
            {
                registro = new Sede();

                Console.WriteLine("Proceso de Registro de Sedes.\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Id de Sede :");
                registro.Id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la sede :");
                registro.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Direccion :");
                registro.Direccion = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Estado /n");
                Console.WriteLine("1.activo / 2.inactivo");
                opcion =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                .
                .
                .
            }
            .
            .
            .
        } while (bandera);
```

2. Para un mejor manejo usa Listas de objetos (List), en este caso listas de Sedes:

```
List<Sede> lstSede = new List<Sede>();


///Para agregar un objeto seria algo como:
lstSede.Add(registro);


//Y para validar que sea hasta 20
lstModel.Count == 20;
```

Comment: gracias auque lo unico malo es que no puedo usar nada ademas de arreglos de objetos, pero vere si con tu ayuda, puedo hacer que el ciclo se detenga y repita cuando el usuario le da si o no gracias

Answer (score 0):

El ciclo do while no te funciona debido a que cuando haces la pregunta que si se desea agregar más sedes tienes que poner bandera en true:

```
Console.WriteLine("Desea registrar mas sedes? SI/NO");
respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
if (respuesta.ToLower().Equals("si")) bandera = true;
```

Ahora, al repetirse el ciclo, lo que hará será reescribir los datos que ya guardaste en el for, para que no suceda eso, te recomiendo que utilices ArrayList, esto hará que puedas agregar registros de forma dinámica.